# parse JSON in javascript phonegap1.7 application

Tags: javascript, objective-c, json, cordova

I have an application that Written with phonegap.
I'm trying to pass "json"(string) from  objective c code to javascript code.
the json contains Hebrew letters,the json looks like this:

```
{
    "cell":[
    {
      "CellType":"HomePageData",
      "HBImage":"https://www.wwe.co.il/he-il/we/we/we/2013/04April/TFS/TFS_Big.jpg",
      "TitleA":"Twentyfourseven ",
      "SubTitle":"50 ש\"ח הנחה בקנייה ב- 250 ש\"ח ",
      "PurchaseType":"0",
      "BenefitId":"101616",
      "BenefitBalance":"",
      "CustomerFirstName":"",
      "CurrentBenefitNum":""
    }]
 }
```

After the json comes to javascript I do Presser wite  jQuery.parseJSON.

Although the json is legal I get the error
Syntax Error or Unexpected token

When deserve json which does not contain Hebrew letters it's ok.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you dont need to parse this json

you can access it directly with:

```
var a= {
            "cell":[
                {
                    "CellType":"HomePageData",
                    "HBImage":"https://www.wwe.co.il/he-il/we/we/we/2013/04April/TFS/TFS_Big.jpg",
                    "TitleA":"Twentyfourseven ",
                    "SubTitle":"50 ש\"ח הנחה בקנייה ב- 250 ש\"ח ",
                    "PurchaseType":"0",
                    "BenefitId":"101616",
                    "BenefitBalance":"",
                    "CustomerFirstName":"",
                    "CurrentBenefitNum":""
                }]
        }


    alert(a.cell[0].CellType)
    alert(a.cell[0].CellType)
    alert(a.cell[0].HBImage)
    alert(a.cell[0].TitleA)
    alert(a.cell[0].SubTitle)
```

and so on..